# How do I detect a remote pause (on headphones) vs. incoming call

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'd like to pause my app when the user pauses music on his headphones.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
  selector:@selector(playbackStateDidChange:) 
  name:MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification 
  object:[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]];
```

works well.  However, this is also triggered on an incoming phone call.

I added

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
  selector:@selector(appLostFocus:) 
  name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification 
  object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```

Unfortunately, this is triggered after the pause is detected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no documented way of doing this. It is probably doable with private APIs, but you know the song.